# Import one cell of data from one spreadsheet to another

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, spreadsheet

I have one spreadsheet that is for global use in which I would like to incorporate one cell of data from various other spreadsheets to refresh anytime there is a change to the source.  So for example:

I have spreadsheets named "Client 1", "Client 2", "Client 3" and so on.   I need cell G24 from each of these sheets to be automatically included in a spreadsheet call "Global Client List" and to automatically refresh whenever there is a change to Client1, Client2, etc..

I can import data from another spreadsheet under the "Data" tab easily enough, however, it imports the entire spreadsheet and will not let me choose just the one cell I need from each.

Can anyone help with this please?

Answer (score 4):

On the Global Client List, go to the cell you want and type `=` (DO NOT HIT ENTER) 
Then go to the sheet with the info (Client 1) and click on the cell you want to copy and hit enter.

Do the same for another Global Client List cell and Client 2, etc.

Comment: This is correct. Note that what we're doing here is creating a link between the workbooks, not *importing* the cell. Typically the term *importing* refers to a one-time operation.